# lubuntu, ESXi 5.5, screen res stuck at 800x600 after upgrade

Tags: upgrade, lubuntu, display-resolution

I had a lubuntu VM that has been working fine for ages. I recently upgraded (to what I assume is the latest version, uname says 4.4.0-31) and now, whilst the monitor settings box offers me a range of resolutions, whichever I pick I always get 800x600.

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling open VM tools, as described here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VMware/Tools

Any ideas?

Comment: Well I've tried reinstalling VMWare Tools but that's made no difference either.

Comment: I am now getting the error dialog "System program problem detected" on reboot, not sure what that means and there doesn't seem to be any more information on what the problem might be.

Comment: If it helps, lspci reports "VMware SGVA II Adapter Kernel Driver in use: vmwgfx Kernet modules: vmwgfx"

Comment: Well I've tried Linux, but after tearing my hair out on this I've given up and taken Microsoft up on their free Windows 10 offer.